# Transmission of live feed from webcam over RF and receive same feed from different pluto

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3, software-defined-radio

Is there any way we can transmit live feed from Rasp Webcam / Webcam and transmit over channel(RF) with Software defined radio, and receive feed from somewhere else ?

I tried to connect everythink in matlab simulink but the delay is totally unacceptable. is there any way we can transmit that over RF ?

Comment: Why does the SDR come into play?  How did you expect to transmit?  I've seen a project where someone made a custom streaming rig with lossy WiFi which was close to what you're asking for.  Otherwise, you need to buy hardware and then just use whatever that hardware uses...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, trying to transmit live video feed from one point to another, but facing a lot more delay in feed. Do you have link to that project ?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to find it.  I searched around for awhile, but didn't see it.  I think it was related to a Pi-powered drone platform, if I remember correctly.  When you say "one point to another", the specifics matter a great deal... how far are you going?  What resolution do you need?  What latency can you tolerate?  And, have you tried one of the many off-the-shelf kits?

Comment: I am roughly looking at almost 3 km from one point to another. I don't need higher resolution and i also don't need audio, only need video. Video can be RGB or grayscale either one works. About latency, it should not be too too large. I had tried but everything else comes with their own software, you can not make more changes according to your need.